# Image URL django media file using AWS S3 expires after a while

Tags: ios, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I use S3 for media file storage on my Django project.

`DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'`

From my iOS project I receive image URLs from Django like

`https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/image-name.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=<AccesKey>&Signature=<Signiture>`

It seems the image URLs are expired after a while(and they probably should).  However this causes a problem. When iOS app user left the app and came back after a while and the app memory was alive, the app tries to load images from expired urls(ex. cell reuse) resulting request error.

I wonder what is a right solution for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your link is so-called [S3 presigned URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-presigned-url.html) and their expiration **can't be disabled**. But you can make it longer. The [maximum](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) expiration time is **7 days** provided the URL is created using IAM user. If you use IAM role or instance role to make the URLs the max times are 36 and 6 hours respectively.

If these times are not satisfactory, you have **three general** options:

- modify your app so that it auto-refreshes expired links.
- don't use pre-sgined URLs. Instead make the s3 object public which never expire.
- again don't use pre-sgined URL, but instead of making your objects public, create CloudFront distribution to [server your objects](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/amazon-s3-amazon-cloudfront-a-match-made-in-the-cloud/) from the CF. This way your bucket and objects are private (not accessible directly), but through CF which can also improve load times of the files.